# How to use c plugins with gradle

Tags: gradle-plugin

I went on https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/dev.guillermo.gradle.c-application and created a parent project with:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'dev.guillermo.gradle.c-application' version '0.3.1' apply false
  id 'dev.guillermo.gradle.c-library' version '0.3.1' apply false
  id 'dev.guillermo.gradle.c-unit-test' version '0.3.1' apply false
}
```

and a child project with

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'dev.guillermo.gradle.c-application'
```

But I can't use `gradle init` in this child project. I must be doing something wrong but I'm really confused by the doc. I thought I could just install a plugin globally and then have the possibility to use `gradle init` and be able to choose `C` as a language.

Is this possible and if yes, how? Otherwise, how can I just create a blank project in C like I would create a Java or Kotlin or C++ project with Gradle?